# How to permanently delete FlaskApp.conf from the Apache2 webserver

Tags: python, python-3.x, apache, flask, wsgi

I am trying to deploy a Flask project using apache2 web server. After I created FlaskApp.conf, I made a mistake in the file. Therefore, when I run `sudo a2ensite FlaskApp` and `service apache2 restart` It does not run because of the error. 
I created FlaskApp.conf using this command:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf
```

Now, When I navigate to `/etc/apache2/sites-available/` and delete the file and then create another one, it still points me to the old error. It is not being updated. It just generates same old file automatically. How to fix this ?

Comment: Sounds like you might have accidentally copied it into the ``sites-enabled`` directory at some point, rather than it being symlinked. Check in the ``sites-enabled`` directory for a separate copy.

Comment: You are right. I found a copy of the file there. I deleted it. But still after restarting the apache2 service. It says it found an error in the file so it cannot restart it. But I already deleted it!! Thanks for the help.